# Is it possible to create an "export to PDF" option?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, pdf

I have a custom post-type "model", and I want to be able to export certain values (eg Name, Height, Shoe Size, etc) and a set number of images from the gallery, from each Model to a PDF.

Ultimately, what I want to be able to do is:

1. From the Admin backend, click an "options tab" or some such
2. select a number of Models,
3. enter an email (or multiple, comma separated emails)
4. Click a "send" button
5. and have the PDFs generated and emailed off without further intervention.

Is this at all possible in WordPress? Or is this too complex? Surely you can do anything with PHP and WordPress ;)

Comment: Did you check out any of the available post to PDF plugins? (i'll let you google that) Have you tried any, did you like / not like them, and for what reasons? Could any of them be extended to accomodate your above needs?

Comment: Doh! I feel very sheepish now - I didn't even look for a plugin (figured this would be difficult, and assumed there wouldn't be any plugins for it) -- I'll investigate those now...

Comment: Looks like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kalins-pdf-creation-station/ is a good place to start :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, please add it as an answer so others can benefit from it too!

Comment: @Jan: No, not really - the "Kalins PDF Creation Station" plugin sort of worked but couldn't get all the info from the custom posts that I needed. Of course, that was a year ago and I haven't checked whether that plugin has been updated in that time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, it is possible.
2. Depends on what you consider to be "too complex".
3. No, you cannot do anything... For example, WordPress and PHP will not bring your deceased loved ones back.